# Showing that $u(x)=(1+x^2)^{-k/2} (\ln(2+x^2))^{-1}$ belongs to $\mathcal W^{1,p}(\Bbb R)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

Consider the function $$u(x)=(1+x^2)^{-\frac{k}{2}} (\ln(2+x^2))^{-1}$$
$x\in\Bbb R$ with $k\in(0,1)$. Prove that $u\in \mathcal W^{1,p}(\Bbb R)$ for every $p\in[1/k,+\infty]$ and that $u\notin L^q(\Bbb R)$ for $q\in[1,1/k)$.

By definition, I have to prove that $u(x)\in L^p(\Bbb R)$ and that the weak derivative $Du$ exists and it belongs to $L^p(\Bbb R)$.

I think I computed $Du$ correctly, but I am having problems showing that $u$ and $Du$ belong to $L^p(\Bbb R).$

How can I show that $$\int_{\Bbb R}|u(x)|^p<+\infty $$ $$\int_{\Bbb R}|Du(x)|^p<+\infty. $$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show you how to prove $u\in\ L^p$. It is clear that $u$ is smooth. We have to look at the behavior of $u$ at $\infty$. For $x$ large,
$$
u(x)^p=(1+x^2)^{-\frac{k\,p}{2}} (\ln(2+x^2))^{-p}\le 2^{-p}|x|^{-k\,p}(\ln|x|)^{-p}.
$$
If $k\,p>1$ this is integrable. If $k\,p=1$, since $p\ge1/k>1$, it is also integrable.

Similar arguments will show that $Du\in L^p$.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail why if $kp>1$ the function is integrable or just tell me where to find the theory that explains it? Thank you very much.

Comment: If $r>1$, then $$\int_1^\infty x^{-r}\,dx=\frac{1}{1-r}x^{-r+1}\Bigr|_1^\infty=\frac{1}{r-1}<\infty.$$

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, but why is it sufficient to show that the function $|x|^{-kp}$ is integrable to say that the whole function $2^{-p}|x|^{-k\,p}(\ln|x|)^{-p}$ is integrable? One last thing, why for $kp=1$ the considered function is integrable even though $\int_{1}^{\infty}x=\ln|x|\rvert_1^\infty$ is not finite? Thanks again.

Comment: Negative powers of the logarithm are bounded near infinity. And $x(\log x)^r$ is integrable if $r>1$.